# How to emit a value in composition API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a datepicker component, which is included in a form.

How do I emit a value from the datepicker component up to the form component in `Vue3 with the composition API?

The unsuccessful solutions so far where:

1. Throws: `context.emit is not a function`

```
setup(context){
....
 function emitDate(){
   context.emit('chosenDate', datepickerValue.value)
 }
}
```

2. Throws: `this.$emit is not a function`

```
setup(){
....
  function emitDate(){
    this.$emit('chosenDate', datepickerValue.value)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass emit, along props to setup:

```
setup(props, { emit }) {

function emitDate(){
  emit('chosenDate', datepickerValue.value)
}
```

or in script setup:

```
const emit = defineEmits(['chosenDate'])

function emitDate() {
  emit('chosenDate', datepickerValue.value)
}
```

Comment: How would that work with the [`<script setup>`](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html) syntax?

Answer (score 1):

The 1st parameter to `setup` is `props`. `context` comes after `setup`, see [setup arguments](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-setup.html#arguments):

```
setup(props, context){
....
 function emitDate(){
   context.emit('chosenDate', datepickerValue.value)
 }
}
```

Or:

```
setup(props, { emit }){
....
 function emitDate(){
   emit('chosenDate', datepickerValue.value)
 }
}
```